# My R code is not working to create wordcloud

Tags: r

I cleaned the text and converted into TDM
Result of TDM showed me 1 Doc and 1 Term
I assume this doesn't make sense

I tried to modify scale for wordcloud but I realized this is much about converting to TDM.

```
library(NLP)
library(tm)

essay <- "sukjin_essay_summary.txt"
essay_2 <- Corpus(VectorSource(essay))

#Data Cleaning
essay_data <- tm_map(essay_2, stripWhitespace)      
essay_data <- tm_map(essay_data, tolower)          
essay_data <- tm_map(essay_data, removeNumbers)     
essay_data <- tm_map(essay_data, removePunctuation) 
essay_data <- tm_map(essay_data, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

#create term document matrix
tdm_essay <- TermDocumentMatrix(essay_data)     #create TDM
TDM <- as.matrix(tdm_essay)
TDM

                      Docs
Terms                  1
sukjinessaysummarytxt  1
```

I expected to have 1 doc and xxx terms but it is only 1 doc and 1 term.

Based on above, my code for wordcloud tells me it can't be plotted.

Comment: `"sukjin_essay_summary.txt"` is used as text, you need to actually read your data, for example `essay <- read.table("sukjin_essay_summary.txt")`

Comment: I followed your advice and I got this error message:
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 2 did not have 1312 element

Comment: I changed the code to this:
essay <- read.table("sukjin_essay_summary.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE, quote = "")

and it worked. Thank you!